# Every non-regular minimal normal subgroup of a doubly transitive group is primitive and simple

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Prove that every non-regular minimal normal subgroup $N$, of a doubly transitive permutation group $G$, is primitive and simple.

I proved that $N$ is primitive; but how I can prove that $N$ is simple?

Comment: If not simple, $N$ would be a direct product of isomorphic simple groups $S$, which would all act transitively. Since they all centralize each other the only possibility is that there are just two factors ($N=S \times S$), both acting regularly. Now you just have show that the normalizer in the symmetric group of such a group $N$ is not doubly transitive.